# android gallery view "stutters" with deferred image loading adapter

Tags: android, android-gallery, android-adapter

I would like to create an deferred loading adapter for use with a `Gallery` widget.

That is to say `getView()` returns an `ImageView` immediately, and later some other mechanism will asynchronously call its `setImageBitmap()` method. I did this by creating a "lazy" `ImageView` that extends `ImageView`.

```
public class GalleryImageView extends ImageView {

    // ... other stuff here ...

    public void setImage(final Looper looper, final int position) {

    final Uri uri = looper.get(position);
    final String path = looper.sharePath(position);

    new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            GalleryBitmap gbmp = new GalleryBitmap(context, uri, path);
            final Bitmap bmp = gbmp.getBitmap(); // all the work is here
            handler.post(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (GalleryImageView.this.getTag().equals(uri)) {
                        setImageBitmap(bmp);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }).start();
}

}
```

When I scroll slowly in the `Gallery`, the center image keeps popping into the center. It's hard to explain, exactly, but it's really annoying.  I also tried the same approach for a spinner adapter and it works perfectly there.

Any ideas?

Comment: I have the same issue.  The scrolling is sticky and the whole thing sort of spazzes left and right before settling back to where it was.  Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: Which version of Android are you using? And does this problem occur when you don't use your custom ImageView? 
Does the issue stop occurring after all the of the images have loaded?

Comment: Can you please describe in details what is the main problem in your `Gallery`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The solution is to implement a more intelligent method of when to fetch thumbnails - it is pointless fetching thumbnails while the user is flinging through the list. Essentially you want something like that implemented in Romain Guy's [Shelves](http://code.google.com/p/shelves/) application.

To get the most responsive Gallery you'll need to implement some form of in-memory cache and do the following:

- Only set an image if it exists in the in-memory cache from your `getView`. Set a flag indicating whether the image was set or whether a download is required. You could also maintain a memory in a cache on the SD card and internal memory, and if a fling is not currently ongoing then show a low res (`inSampleSize` set to 16 or 8) version which will be visible when just scrolling through - the high res version will load when the user lets go and settles on an image.
- Add an `OnItemSelectedListener` (and make sure to call `setCallbackDuringFling(false)` when initializing) that downloads new thumbnails for all the visible items that require a download *only if the users finger is up* (you can use `getFirstVisiblePosition` and `getLastVisiblePosition` to find the range of views visible)
- Also when the user lifts their finger check to see 1. if the selected position changed since the user put their finger down and if so 2. whether a download was initiated due to your `OnItemSelectedListener` - if it wasn't then initiate one. This is to catch the case where no flinging occurs, and thus `OnItemSelected` never does anything because it is always called with the finger down in this situation. I'd use a Handler to delay starting the downloading by the animation time of your gallery (make sure to clear any delayed messages posted to this handler whenever `onItemSelected` is called or when you get an `ACTION_DOWN` event.
- After an image is downloaded check if any visible views requested this image then and update those views

Also be aware that the default Gallery component does not properly implement View recycling (it assumes each position in the adapter has a unique view, and also clears the recycler of these items when they go offscreen making it pretty pointless). **Edit:** on more looking it isn't pointless - but it's not a recycler in terms of next/previous views, rather it serves to avoid having to call `getView` for the current views during layout changes.

This means the `convertView` parameter passed to your `getView` method will more often that not be null, meaning you'll be inflating a lot of views (which is expensive) - see my answer to [Does a replacement for Gallery with View recycling exist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5789879/android-does-a-replacement-for-gallery-widget-with-view-recycling-exist) for some hints on that. (PS: I have since modified that code - I would use a different recycle bin for layout phases and scroll phases, in the layout phase place and retrieve the views in the layout recycle bin according to their position, and DO NOT call getView if the view you get from the bin is non-null since it will be exactly the same view; also clear the layout recycle bin after the layout phase -- this makes things a bit more snappier)

PS: Also be very careful with what you do in `OnItemSelected` - namely unless it's in the places mentioned above then try to do as little as possible. For instance I was setting some text in a `TextView` above my Gallery in `OnItemSelected`. Just moving this call into the same points as where I updated thumbnails made a noticable difference.

Comment: Ah, thank you.  This seems like it will get me headed in a reasonable direction.  Though at this point I may punt on the work item and just go for a fixed number of static images and cut scrolling all together.  At least for this version.  :)

Comment: so it won't load any image until the user selects something in the gallery? how does the user know what they want to select if they can't see them? i must be missing something. it seems like you'd want to start the download / load image task when the fling motion stops, not when an item is selected. how can one tell when the gallery is done scrolling? the approach taken by the gallery app is to load a downsampled image initially which is faster, then load the full res version later. this doesn't work if the problem is network download though.

Comment: In that case show a loading spinner until the image is downloaded. Also the Gallery does create views that are not visible, so downloading thumbnails in `onItemSelected` will download images for a few views to the left and right. If you want to tell when the gallery is done scrolling - that is when your OnItemSelected listener is called and no finger is down - the listener is called everytime an item moves into the center.

Comment: Yes you'd either need to call `setSelection` at the start to trigger a thumbnail download or manually start a thumbnails download.

Comment: Great answer, I dont see how this gets around the layout pass issue i describe in my post on this page, which was causing the stutter for me (and I believe the OP also)

Answer (score 12):

I have an answer for you!

When any of the `setImage...` methods are called on `ImageView` in internally a layout pass is requested, for example, `setImageBitmap()` as above is defined as such

```
public void setImageBitmap(Bitmap bm) {
    setImageDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(mContext.getResources(), bm));
}
```

which calls

```
public void setImageDrawable(Drawable drawable) {
    if (mDrawable != drawable) {
        mResource = 0;
        mUri = null;
        updateDrawable(drawable);
        requestLayout(); //layout requested here!
        invalidate();
    }
}
```

which has the effect of the gallery 'snapping' to the center of the image thats currently closest to the center of the gallery.

What I have done to prevent this is have the View thats loading into the Gallery have a explicit height and width (in `dip`s) and using an `ImageView` subclass that ignores layout requests. This works as the gallery still has a layout pass initially but does not bother doing this every time an image in the gallery changes, which I imagine would only need to happen if the gallery views had their width and height set to `WRAP_CONTENT`, which we dont. Note that as `invalidate()` is still called in `setImageDrawable()` the image will still be drawn when set.

My very simple `ImageView` subclass below!

```
/**
 * This class is useful when loading images (say via a url or file cache) into
 * ImageView that are contained in dynamic views (Gallerys and ListViews for
 * example) The width and height should be set explicitly instead of using
 * wrap_content as any wrapping of content will not be triggered by the image
 * drawable or bitmap being set (which is normal behaviour for an ImageView)
 * 
 */
public class ImageViewNoLayoutRefresh extends ImageView
{
    public ImageViewNoLayoutRefresh(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
    {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public ImageViewNoLayoutRefresh(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public ImageViewNoLayoutRefresh(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void requestLayout()
    {
        // do nothing - for this to work well this image view should have its dims
        // set explicitly
    }
}
```

edit: i should mention that the onItemSelected approaches can also work, but as I needed to hook into that while flinging was taking place I came up with the above, which I think is more flexible approach

Comment: wonderful. I tried to implement my own ImageView that doesn't call the requestLayout() when set a drawable but you can simply override requestLayout and do nothing. Ty man

Answer (score 2):

This might be a bug in the Gallery's onLayout method. Check out http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=16171 for a possible workaround.

Comment: while this is the same issue i dont believe this solution will work. While it will stop all layout requests during scroll (and 250ms afterwards) it will not stop layout requests during fling (see onFling for Gallery). As far as I can see there is no way to tell when a fling has finished due to all the associated methods and fields being private (in Gallery), so the best i think you could do (apart from following my answer on this page) is to work it out from some function of the velocity passed into this method, but looking at the FlingRunnable and Scroller classes this is not simple :)